# Change permisions on /usr and /usr/local to link Homebrew package

Tags: command-line, homebrew, permission, mojave, sip

How does one change permissions for `/usr` or `/usr/local`? I tried doing `sudo chmod 775 /usr/local`, but it says

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/local: Operation not permitted`
```

so I ran `ls -l /usr` and it showed

```
drwxr-xr-x   17 root  wheel    544 Nov 20 14:08 local
```

(it also showed the stuff for the other things in there, but those are irrelevant). Also, why do I have to use `sudo`, as I have admin privileges, shouldn't that be enough?

I am trying to change the permissions so that I can install [simple2d](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d) using Homebrew. When I run `brew link simple2d`, it says that it can't symlink into /usr/local/Frameworks, but Frameworks doesn't exist, so I tried to create it, and it won't let me because of permissions.

I am using macOS Mojave. On a mac that has [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899)

When I run `brew doctor` it outputs

```
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7m-config
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3-config

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/lauxlib.h
  /usr/local/include/lua.h
  /usr/local/include/luaconf.h
  /usr/local/include/lualib.h
  /usr/local/include/node/android-ifaddrs.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_build.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_rules.h
  /usr/local/include/node/ares_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/libplatform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/libplatform/v8-tracing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/nameser.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h
  /usr/local/include/node/node_version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/aes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/BSD-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/VC-WIN64A/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/aix64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin-i386-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/darwin64-x86_64-cc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-aarch64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-armv4/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-elf/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-ppc64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x32/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux-x86_64/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux32-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/linux64-s390x/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris-x86-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/archs/solaris64-x86_64-gcc/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/asn1t.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bio.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/blowfish.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/bn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/buffer.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/camellia.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cast.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/cms.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/comp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/conf_api.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/crypto.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/des_old.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dso.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/dtls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/e_os2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ebcdic.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ec.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdh.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ecdsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/engine.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/err.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/evp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/hmac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/idea.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/krb5_asn.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/kssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/lhash.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/md5.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/mdc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/modes.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/obj_mac.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/objects.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ocsp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/opensslv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ossl_typ.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pem2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs12.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pkcs7.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/pqueue.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rand.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rc4.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ripemd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/rsa.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/safestack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/seed.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/sha.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/srtp.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl2.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl23.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ssl3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/stack.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/symhacks.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/tls1.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ts.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/txt_db.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/ui_compat.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/whrlpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509_vfy.h
  /usr/local/include/node/openssl/x509v3.h
  /usr/local/include/node/pthread-barrier.h
  /usr/local/include/node/stdint-msvc2008.h
  /usr/local/include/node/tree.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-aix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-bsd.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-darwin.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-errno.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-linux.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-os390.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-sunos.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-threadpool.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-unix.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv-win.h
  /usr/local/include/node/uv.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-debug.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-experimental.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector-protocol.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-inspector.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-platform.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-profiler.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-testing.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-util.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8-version.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8.h
  /usr/local/include/node/v8config.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zconf.h
  /usr/local/include/node/zlib.h

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/liblua.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2
  python
  nano
  lua
  hamlib
  simple2d
```

Comment: First remove macports (or use macports which you already have instead of Homebrew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do `sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks` to make the Frameworks folder.
Second, `sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*` to give you the proper permissions to do stuff.
Third, `brew link simple2d` or whatever package you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to modify the `/usr` or `/usr/local` permissions yourself to install any package using Homebrew.

simple2d is not available with core (default) Homebrew tap. To install it, follow the instructions as mentioned in the [project Readme file on GitHub repository](https://github.com/simple2d/simple2d/blob/master/README.md). Run `brew update` followed by `brew upgrade`. Thereafter run the following commands:

> brew tap simple2d/tap
>
> brew install simple2d

This should install `simple2d` on your Mac via Homebrew. To ensure the sanity of the Homebrew installation itself, run `brew doctor`.

Comment: I did that, and it said `Error: Could not symlink Frameworks/Simple2D
/usr/local/Frameworks is not writable.`

Comment: What's the output of running `brew doctor`?

Comment: it outputted a ton of stuff, i am excluding the "unexpected header file" well as a lot other stuff.
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure`

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You may want to temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macportsWarning

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
  python@2
  python
  nano
  lua
  hamlib
  simple2d

Comment: @Mining15 Please edit the question and paste the output as is.

Comment: I did some research and found out that system integrity protection is probably messing with stuff, or rather, preventing me from messing with stuff

Comment: @Mining15 And you shouldn't need to mess with System Integrity Protection (SIP) in general, at least not in cases like install Homebrew packages.

Comment: then how do I install it, as it needs to be linked (`brew link simple2d`) and to link it, brew needs to write to `/usr/local/Frameworks`?